# Flutter_form_builder errors

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety, flutter-form-builder

I'm trying to use `flutter_form_builder: ^7.1.0` with [form_builder_validators](https://pub.dev/packages/form_builder_validators) to create a form, but a getting `undefined` errors at

`onChanged: _onChanged,` and `validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose`.

I tried following the [example at flutter_form_builder](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder#input-widgets) but the example seems to be either incomplete or not up to date. When I try to add `autovalidate: true,` I get another undefined error. How can I fix this?

```
class _CreateCompanyViewState extends State<CreateCompanyView> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

---

```
 FormBuilder(
                 
                key: _formKey,

                child: Column(
          
                  children: <Widget>[

                    FormBuilderTextField(

                      name: 'age',          

                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                     
                      labelText: 'This value is passed along to the [Text.maxLines] attribute of the [Text] widget used to display the hint text.',
                      
                      ),
              
                      onChanged: _onChanged,
            
                        validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([
               
                          FormBuilderValidators.required(context),

                          FormBuilderValidators.numeric(context),
                        
                          FormBuilderValidators.max(context, 70),
               
                        ]),
              
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            
                        ),

                  Row(

                    children: <Widget>[
        
                      Expanded(
            
                        child: MaterialButton(
              
                          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
              
                        child: Text("Submit", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),

                          onPressed: () {
                
                            _formKey.currentState?.save();
                
                            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  
                              print(_formKey.currentState!.value);
                
                            } else {
                  
                              print("validation failed");
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
          
                      SizedBox(width: 20),
          
                      Expanded(
            
                        child: MaterialButton(

                          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
              
                          child: Text("Reset", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
              
                          onPressed: () {

                            _formKey.currentState!.reset();
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              )
            ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormBuilderValidators` is not handling null value. You need to check null value, then perform others validators.

```dart
validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([
  (val) {
    return val == null ? "Field is empty" : null;
  },
  FormBuilderValidators.required(context), 
/// others validator
]),
```

Comment: This made no difference, the undefined errors remained.

Comment: Can you recheck the parenthesis, try `flutter clean`  and restarting the IDE. Also make sure to add [form_builder_validators](https://pub.dev/packages/form_builder_validators) package.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting issues with form_builder_validators of lately, it means you are using a new version form_builder_validators that still have bugs.

What to do, you have to revers your flutter version and download flutter sdk 3.7.12 on the link below
3.7.12
[DOWNLOAD Flutter SDK - V 3.7.12](https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/releases/stable/windows/flutter_windows_3.7.12-stable.zip)

**THEN**
Downgrade your packages too to

```
  flutter_form_builder: ^7.7.0
  form_builder_validators: ^8.3.0
```

At least I am sure those two work properly.